# Context is null in fragment before start of lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-context

There is a huge bug I am trying to figure out in my latest project using Kotlin. So how the app works is that it has a Bottom Navigation Activity, and on click on the icons on the Bottom menu, it replaces the container with the respected fragment. On onCreate of the activity, I instantiate all the different fragments with a function defined in a companionObject within the fragments, which returns itself (kind of like a static factory method in java):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        {...}

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance()
        fragment2 = Fragment2.newInstance()
}
```

Then I have this switch to replace the container to the respected fragment on click:

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.f1 -> {
                replaceFragment(fragment1)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.f2 -> {
                replaceFragment(fragment2)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
{...}
fun replaceFragment(destFragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, destFragment)
            .addToBackStack(destFragment.toString())
            .commit()
    }
```

The fragments are communicating. If you where to click on both fragments, and thereby cause their lifecycles to execute, the code works fine. However, if you do changes in frag1, invoking a communication between the fragments, without having clicked on frag2 in advance, the app crashes. The reason is this line in frag2:

```
fun saveList(){
        val sharedpref : SharedPreferences = context!!.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
        {...}
    }
```

Turns out that the context is null, if the user has never invoked the frag2 lifecycle by clicking it. Any ideas to how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity context for these case

```
fun saveList() {
  activity?.let {
    val sharedpref: SharedPreferences =
      it.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
      {  }

  }
}
```